# React Native Navigation Code for this requirement

Tags: generics, button, navigation

React Native Navigation Code for this requirement.

I am developing a mobile app that consists of multiple screens. One of the main screens is the home screen, where users can find a Plus button. This button is used to create a new record for a specific entity. For example, there are three entities: Employee, Department, and Designation.

When a user is on the Designation screen and clicks the Plus button, the app should navigate them to the Add Designation screen. Similarly, if the user is on any other screen corresponding to a specific entity and clicks the Plus button, the app should navigate them to the respective "Add" screen for that entity.

I am trying to resolve the issue with if else and switch case

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem, you can pass a function on onPress where the function will take the path from your route parameter. Based on your path route you can pass it in your function which will programmatically redirect you to your corresponding Entities.